# Angular 5 Как подключить директиву?

Tags: angularjs, модули, angular-directive, angular5

Взял стартовый пример директивы:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: '[btn-loading]'
})
export class BtnLoadingDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.elementRef);
  }

}
```

И хочу ее использовать:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn branded btn-block" [btn-loading]="true" [disabled]="submitted && loginForm.invalid">Sign in</button>
```

**[btn-loading]="true"**

И ловлю ошибку:

> Can't bind to 'btn-loading' since it isn't a known property of
>   'button'

Хотя в модуле я все подключил:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [BtnLoadingDirective, AuthComponent, AuthLoginComponent]
})
export class AuthPagesModule {}
```

Comment: кажется вместо `[btn-loading]="true"` надо писать просто `btn-loading`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить биндинг в дитрективу

```
@Input('btn-loading') isLoading:boolean
```

Comment: Давно уже нашел причину. И Вы правы - для [] нужeн биндинг.